# What can one do with the original used VMs , once the migration of servers are done using AWS server migration service

Tags: amazon-web-services, migration, cloud, server-migration

As we know ,  AWS server migration service or SMS automates the migration of your on  VMware vsphere, Microsoft Hyper-V and Azure virtual machines to the AWS cloud as AMI which we will run on EC2 instance. Once this migration is completely done for both OS/data/application , what to do with the original used VMs we were using previously. Should we sell them ?

Comment: Are these VMs running in your organization's data center ?